# Can I rely on Operating System (OS) Anti Virus (AV) scanning to scan FSX file shares?

Tags: amazon-web-services, antivirus, amazon-fsx

I have an EC2 instance with an Windows OS with anti virus installed.

I have a requirement to attach a file share to the OS where the application is hosted. The file share is  Amazon Fsx ( Amazon's native windows file system).

Can I rely on the OS scanning the Fsx file share or should the Fsx have its own file scanning capability?